# How to host angularjs1 app on nginx that hosts other applications

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have an angularjs one application in a `dist` folder. I would like to host it on my nginx. My nginx currently hosts multiple applications via `proxy_pass`. I've never hosted a static html app on nginx so I'm not sure what to do.

- I have my app in `dist` folder on the nginx server at location `/home/anthony/dist`.
- My nginx configuration has only a single file in  `ssl_proxy` in `sites-enabled` folder
- Under `sites-available` I have a `locations` folder that contains various `.conf` files.

I've created a new file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/locations/mystatic.conf` and placed the following content in it:

```
location /mystatic {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /home/anthony/dist/index.html;
}
```

But after restarting nginx and going to `http://<myserver>/mystatic` I get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
location /mystatic {
    index index.html;
    alias /home/anthony/dist;
}
```

Comment: adding `index index.html` gives a 404. However, removing that line and just keeping `alias /home/anthony/dist; fetches a 403 error.

Comment: Here is the access.log with 403 error and permissions on the `dist` folder and my conf file https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/2c0d17593ca6f868e03f0d4b385d1326

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Chown to www-data:www-data on the folder and the files in it.

Comment: will that work? because my `nginx.conf` has `user nginx` in it

Comment: `chown: invalid user:  www-data:www-data ` I have done `chown -R nginx:nginx /home/anthony/dist` but that also gives 403 error...

Comment: Yes, use that. Sorry, it's typically www-data but sometimes it's nginx. Also rather than store the files in your home directory you should put them in /var/www/html or something similar.

Comment: Add the 'index index.html' back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135480/discussion-between-anthony-and-faisal-memon).